# NSTableViewDataSource or NSArrayController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I need to load data dynamically as a user scrolls through an `NSTableView`. For example, the table might display 50 rows, and as it scrolls further I need to fetch more data from the network. The number of of objects/rows is known beforehand, so I want the table to have the right number of rows from the start, but showing empty cells while data is loading.

I'm using Core Data so it's easy to connect the table to my model using bindings. This would also take care of cells being updated as data comes in and is parsed. I've tried to figure out how I could do this by subclassing `NSArrayController` but from what I can tell there is no information flowing from the table to the controller about which rows actually need data. Therefore, I'm thinking of implementing `NSTableViewDataSource` instead, where I can easily check if the table has scrolled beyond the rows for which data is available. On the other hand, I don't know if I will get cells automatically updating as easily with this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, here's my own answer:

**Yes**, you need to implement NSTableViewDataSource on a controller, observe changes on the data and call `reloadData` manually on the table when changes occur. The main reason for doing this is that you can defer loading of data until it's actually needed (when the table view scrolls). Using the data source protocol keeps you informed of which indexes are requested.